# Lost "VGA Display" color profile in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, color-profiles

OS X Display settings used to have a color profile named `VGA Display`, which I found quite usefully for finding color problems before hooking up a projector.  Currently, this profile (along with a number of others I've collected from projectors in the past year) is not available.  I'm currently OS X 10.6.6 and my best guess is the profiles got wiped out during the last upgrade.

None of the available color profiles seem to stink quite enough.  Am I overlooking a renamed profile?  Is there somewhere I could get a 'VGA Display' profile to install on my computer?

Comment: Have you un-checked the checkbox labeled "Show profile for this display only"?

Comment: Yes, "Show profiles for this display only" is unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin,

generic color profiles live here on my machine:
`/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles`

the ones I see for connected displays here:
`/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays`

I have a hunch they were generated when I first connected the respective devices, based on the file creation dates.

and I see some more in the display control panel from
`/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/Recommended/`

those were installed with Photoshop.

When I make something available in `/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays` then I can see it in the display control panel.

However - I'm doing really well since I calibrate, with a hardware device. No worries since. Get someone to calibrate your display, Colormunkis and their siblings are becoming more and more common. And the just forget whatever other profiles you still have lying around :-)

Comment: The answer is "When I first connected the respective devices"  My "VGA Display" is back, and suspect it's because I hooked up to a projector again.  I exported it, so no more running away ;^)

Comment: exported? as in "copied" or "duplicated" ? Have a look at the "desc" field in the profile itself, because this is the sctring that gets shown in selection lists, independently from the actual filename...

Comment: oh, and I will try to trace how the new profile gets o the folder - I have one unknown beamer to connect to next week.